# Disable Reminders "due" date

Tags: icloud, macos, reminders

Generally, there is no option to set a "due" date and time for a reminder, just a "remind me" date and time.  However, often when I have a reminder and I change the "remind me" time a "due" time appears as so:

[image: due date]

The "due" date and time does not have a check box like "remind me".  How do I get rid of the due date?  The due date seems to be related to a bug where the reminder keeps notifying me and appearing on my screen before it's supposed to remind me (as per the "remind me" date).  How can I fix this and in general prevent it from happening?

Comment: Have you tried checking `On a Day` then unchecking it? I’ve seen the `due date` before, and it usually resulted from moving a repeating reminder that was past due, although it’s difficult to reproduce.

Comment: @Phong it is difficult to reproduce.  My current workaround is to simply delete the reminder and recreate it.  I might have tried your solution but I'll double check when it happens again to see if it works.

Comment: @Phong this happened again and I tried checking *On a Day* and unchecking it several times to no avail.  I even tried checking the box and clicking *Done* but that also did nothing, as did changing both dates (the "remind me" date and the "due" date).

Comment: It just so happens that it happened to me today as well. I will post my workaround as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Quick Answer**
To remove the **Due** field, simply update it to match your **Alarm** (both day and time).

**How To Reproduce**
Add a new scheduled reminder by tapping the empty line at the bottom of today’s **Scheduled** list (on iOS). Then instead of tapping **Done**, tap the ⓘ and change the **Alarm**. With a poor connection the **Due** popped up field every time.

**How To Keep This From Happening**
Tap **Done** (in the upper right corner, under the alarm clock graphic) after creating a new reminder. Then wait for the network activity indicator (next to your network symbol) to stop spinning before setting a new **Alarm**. The reminder should have shifted into its correct, sorted position by then.

I have to wonder what the purpose of this **Due** field is, since there isn’t a way for the user to set it directly. It seems like something that’s used internally by iOS and macOS that’s never supposed to be exposed to the user.

It is worth noting that the web app at iCloud.com used to have a checkbox to add the **Due** field. It has since been retired, though it is still accessible via AppleScript.

Comment: I confirmed this behavior with my own device.  This workaround *is* what I asked for, although it's such a hassle to set the new date I might just go back to removing and re-adding reminders.  Maybe.  Thanks.

Comment: I have noticed some apps that sync with Reminders deliberately add the Due Date field to reminders they create, which suggests that the Due Date field is not an internal piece of Reminders being inadvertently exposed. It seems more like a forgotten (or merely unused by Apple) piece of the Reminders API.

Answer (score 1):

May be this problem is only Mac related, due a hidden or forgotten CHECK BOX after the text **Due date** and before the **Date**.

To add Due Date on Mac:

1. You can create a Due Date with Automator. Make a workflow with Create a reminder, run it and set a **Due date** different to the 'Alert date'.
2. The 'Remind Me' app (free on Mac App Store) can do so too.
3. Other non-Apple apps that create non Apple-Standard info in the reminders, in this case, a 'Due date' different from the 'Remind me on a day' date. For example, testing it with GoodTask if I set a 'Due date', GoodTask activate the Alert checkbox too. In Apple Reminders is shown as usual: 'Remind me on a date: ...' If I uncheck the 'Due date' in Goodtask, the 'Alert' field goes off too. But if I uncheck only the 'Alert' checkbox, letting the 'Due date' activated, the same reminder in Apple Reminders changed to 'Due date' without the 'Remind me on a day' checked.

iOS Reminders:

You can add both **Remind me on a date** and **Due Date** on iOS Reminders- This is a Mac missing feature (Mac OS 11.12.6, I don’t know if this was fixed on High Sierra).

To delete the Due Date on Mac:

A missing checkbox could disable de Due date, but it’s not possible without that checkbox.

1. Making match both date and time (as @user11633 said) you can get rid of the **Due date**.
2. You may look if you created that reminder in other app (BusyCal, GoodTask, Fantastical...)  If you do so, you can delete the 'Due date' on that app.
3. Mac app Reminders have a bug because if you have **Remind me on a date** and **Due date**, check the **Remind me on a location**, select any option (**When I Arrive**, or **When I Leave**), then, click to uncheck **Remind me on a day** it deletes the **Due Date**, keeping the alert on. It's crazy.

By the way, I've discovered that you can change, in Mac, both the 'Due date' and the 'Remind me' date dragging the reminder to the calendar on the bottom left, or drop it into the 'Scheduled' field (at top of the Lists sidebar) to set the date to Today.

If you select the due date clicking on the numbers, or with Tab key, then you can change the date and time with cursor up/down. The changes can (some times not) affect to both Due Date and Remind Me (keeping the time difference).

In menu Edit it shows: Undo changes in 'Due Date', but there's no visible way to 'unckeck' the Due Date field. This is a proof that the feature exists, but a the checkbox is missing.